# Marking with Mesh, Distinct coloring, Ticksing, and Plotting table of complex function with parametric plot

Tags: plotting, legending, mesh, parametric-functions, marker

Here is my todo list and what i've done:

1. Using `FrameTicks` on specific points only (failed).
2. Plotting six graphs with `Table` on `ParametricPlot` (Success).
3. Marking each graph with `Mesh` "independently" (have no idea, but have the related topic, See [8](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/241185/marking-a-continuous-plot-with-the-same-subinterval-based-on-the-range-of-the-co)).
4. Coloring each graph (failed).
5. Legending each graph (works but only the first graph).

I will explain the point $(3)$ with this sketch (simplification drawing):

[image]

The distance between two marks based on the codomain should have the same length.

Here is my attempt without different marks:

```
M = 5;
markers = {{"*", 25}, {"@", 10}, {"$", 15}, {"#", 10}, {"&", 
    10}, {"+", 25}};
mesh = {Most@Subdivide[-2, 2.8, 5]};
eqn = Table[
   2 M/t (\[Theta] Cot[\[Theta]] + I  \[Theta]), {t, {9, 19, 24, 29, 
     39, 49}}];
ticks = {{{-5, -2}, -4, -3, -2, -1, 0, 1}, {-Pi, Pi}, {}, {}};
graph = ParametricPlot[ReIm@eqn, {\[Theta], -3.14, 3.14}, 
  AspectRatio -> 1, 
  FrameLabel -> {"Re(s(\[Theta]))", "Im(s(\[Theta]))"}, 
  Frame -> True, FrameTicks -> ticks, PlotStyle -> Thick, 
  Axes -> False, MeshFunctions -> {#2 &}, Mesh -> mesh, 
  MeshStyle -> PointSize[Large], 
  PlotLegends -> 
   Placed[LineLegend[{"t=9", "t=19", "t=24", "t=29", "t=39", "t=49"}, 
     LegendFunction -> "Frame"], {.85, .8}]]
```

The Output:

[image]

The markings still sharing the same scale and not evaluated on each graph, has no coloring, `FrameTicks` doesn't work, and the Legend only shows $1$ graph.

Meanwhile, when i try to add the different markings, it becomes messy and there's an error message

```
M = 5;
markers = {{"*", 25}, {"@", 10}, {"$", 15}, {"#", 10}, {"&", 
    10}, {"+", 25}};
mesh = {Most@Subdivide[-2, 2.8, 5]};
eqn = Table[
   2 M/t (\[Theta] Cot[\[Theta]] + I  \[Theta]), {t, {9, 19, 24, 29, 
     39, 49}}];
ticks = {{{-5, -2}, -4, -3, -2, -1, 0, 1}, {-Pi, Pi}, {}, {}};
graph = ParametricPlot[ReIm@eqn, {\[Theta], -3.14, 3.14}, 
   AspectRatio -> 1, 
   FrameLabel -> {"Re(s(\[Theta]))", "Im(s(\[Theta]))"}, 
   Frame -> True, FrameTicks -> ticks, PlotStyle -> Thick, 
   Axes -> False, MeshFunctions -> {#2 &}, Mesh -> mesh, 
   MeshStyle -> PointSize[Large], 
   PlotLegends -> 
    Placed[LineLegend[{"t=9", "t=19", "t=24", "t=29", "t=39", "t=49"},
       LegendFunction -> "Frame"], {.85, .8}]];
meshStyles = 
  Association[
   Join @@ Cases[
     graph, {___, Directive[___, c_?ColorQ, ___], Line[x_]} :> 
      Thread[x -> c], All]];
styleToMarkers = 
  AssociationThread[ColorData[97] /@ Range[3], Style @@@ markers];
graph /. Point[
   x_] :> ({meshStyles@#, Text[styleToMarkers[meshStyles@#], #]} & /@ 
    x)
```

Output:

[image]

And i wish i have something like this:

[image]

Hope my question isn't too much and you want to help me. Thanks in advance!

Here is my references:

1. [parametricplot-table-of-complex-functions-in-several-graphs](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/189799/parametricplot-table-of-complex-functions-in-several-graphs)
2. [coloring-parametricplot-of-several-complex-functions](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/189492/coloring-parametricplot-of-several-complex-functions)
3. [color-parametric-plot-by-parameter](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/129287/color-parametric-plot-by-parameter)
4. [marking-a-continuous-plot-with-the-same-subinterval-based-on-the-range-of-the-co](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/241185/marking-a-continuous-plot-with-the-same-subinterval-based-on-the-range-of-the-co)
5. [how-do-i-reverse-the-axis-in-parametricplot](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/13253/how-do-i-reverse-the-axis-in-parametricplot)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1.** Wrap the first argument of `ParametricPlot` with `Evaluate` to get the 6 curves treated as separate curves so that each has its own style end legend entry.

**2.** Add `LegendMarkers -> markers` in `LineLegend[...]`

**3.** Replace `3` in the definition of `styleToMarkers` with `Length @ markers`.

**4.** Define `ticks` as `ticks = {{{-Pi, Pi}, Automatic}, {Range[-5, 1], Automatic}};`

**5.** Add the option `Exclusions -> None`: This makes each curve a single line rather than two lines, and ensures that `meshStyles` works without modification.

**6.** Use the options `MeshFunctions -> {"ArcLength"}` and `Mesh -> 5` to add 5 markers that divide each curve into 6 equal-length pieces.

**7.** Add the option `RegionFunction -> (-5 <= # <= 2 &)`: This ensures that the underlying curves produced by the kernel do not extend to the left of -5. (`PlotRange` does not guarantee this.) Without this option, `MeshFunctions -> {"ArcLength"}` will not give the desired result.

With all these changes:

```
graph = ParametricPlot[Evaluate[ReIm@eqn], {θ, -3.14, 3.14},
   PlotStyle -> Thick, AspectRatio -> 1, 
   FrameLabel -> {"Re(s(θ))", "Im(s(θ))"},
   Frame -> True, FrameTicks -> ticks, Axes -> False, 
   ImageSize -> Large,
   MeshStyle -> PointSize[Large],
   MeshFunctions -> {"ArcLength"},
   Mesh -> 5,
   Exclusions -> None,
   RegionFunction -> (-5 <= # <= 2 &),
   PlotRange -> {{-5, 2}, Automatic},
   PlotRangePadding -> Scaled[.02],
   PlotLegends -> Placed[LineLegend[{"t=9", "t=19", "t=24", "t=29", "t=39", "t=49"},
       LegendFunction -> "Frame", LegendMarkers -> markers], {.85, .8}]];

meshStyles = Association[Join @@ Cases[graph, 
   {___, Directive[___, c_?ColorQ, ___], Line[x_]} :> Thread[x -> c], All]];

styleToMarkers = AssociationThread[ColorData[97] /@ Range[Length @ markers], 
   Style @@@ markers];

ticks = {{{-Pi, Pi}, Automatic}, {Range[-5, 1], Automatic}};

graph /. Point[x_] :> ({meshStyles@#, Text[styleToMarkers[meshStyles@#], #]} & /@ x)
```

[image]
To add markers at the start and end of curves use

```
graph /. {Point[x_] :> ({meshStyles@#, Text[styleToMarkers[meshStyles@#], #]} & /@ x), 
 Line[x_] :> {Line[x], 
    {meshStyles@#, Text[styleToMarkers[meshStyles@#], #]} & /@ x[[{1, -1}]]}}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for the help!

Comment: Hi. How to my third problem? The marking still have the same common place. How to work with pattern since the scale of each graph is different? Thanks.

Comment: @user516076,  do you get  what you meed with `MeshFunctions -> {#3 &}` and `Mesh -> 5`?

Comment: error sir. Isn't `#3 &` for 3d?

Comment: maybe instead of mesh i'm thinking about making listplot, then specifying the number of the dots. But sadly i don't know how to do that. Keep getting error and using ComplexListPlot doesn't help.

Comment: what is error message you are getting? Btw, `#3&` is the same as `Function[{a,b,c},c]`, that is, take the third argument which, in `ParametricPlot[func[θ], {θ, θmin, θmax}]`, is `θ`. See [MeshFunctions >> Details](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MeshFunctions.html) for a list of mesh function arguments for various `*Plot` functions.

Comment: @user516076, please see the substantially revised version.